# Node Exits when DB error caught and re-thrown in Express Application

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Below piece of code is in an express 4.0 router. I have knowingly given a wrong SELECT statement (table doesn't exist). clientErrorHandler() is called as expected and then Node is exiting(crashing).
Adding try/catch is not helpful because of async nature of DB call.
When I rectify the SELECT statement everything works as expected.

```
router.use(function (req, res, next){
  DBCon.DBConUtil.pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
    if (err) throw new DBDataError("Error while getting connection from pool");
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM employee' ,function(err,rows){
      if(err){
        connection.release();
        throw new DBDataError("Error while executing select statement using pool connection.");
      }else{
        res.rows1 = rows;
        logger.info("App-Instance-name: %s, filename: %s, MessageContent: %s", process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE, __filename, JSON.stringify({message: "Data received from Db using connection pool: ", data: rows}));
        connection.release();
      }
    });
  });
  res.send(JSON.stringify(res.rows1));
  //next();
});

router.use(clientErrorHandler);
router.use(errorHandler);

function clientErrorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  logger.info("App-Instance-name: %s, filename: %s, Cookies: %s", process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE, __filename, JSON.stringify(req.cookies));
  logger.info("App-Instance-name: %s, filename: %s, stack trace: ", process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE, __filename, err.stack);
  return next(err);
}

function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(500);
  res.send('Error in handing DB calls.');
}

function DBDataError(message) {
  this.constructor.prototype.__proto__ = Error.prototype
  Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor)
  this.name = this.constructor.name
  this.message = message
}
```

Two additional information :-

(1)If same DBDataError is throw when there is no actual DB error outside the "if(err)" then clientErrorHandler() is called as expected and node doesn't exit. This shows that script is able to throw and catch the error as expected.

(2)If DB error is caught using "if(err)" and I don't throw new DBDataError then clientErrorHandler() is not called which is also expected behaviour and node doesn't exit. This shows that node is not crashing because of DB exception.

Any experts can throw some light on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should read up a bit more about JavaScript and callbacks, since your res.send is outside of the callback.

The order of functions called (after the router.use callback started), assuming a non-error flow

1. DBCon.DBConUtil.pool.getConnection
2. res.send
3. JSON.stringify (with an undefined property)
4. connection.query
5. logger.info
6. connection.release

Either of the following 2 should fix it:
1:

```
router.use(function (req, res, next){
  DBCon.DBConUtil.pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
    if (err) throw new DBDataError("Error while getting connection from pool");
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM employee' ,function(err,rows){
      if(err){
        connection.release();
        throw new DBDataError("Error while executing select statement using pool connection.");
        res.send(JSON.stringify({error: 'DB error'}));
      }else{
        res.rows1 = rows;
        logger.info("App-Instance-name: %s, filename: %s, MessageContent: %s", process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE, __filename, JSON.stringify({message: "Data received from Db using connection pool: ", data: rows}));
        connection.release();
        res.send(JSON.stringify(res.rows1));
      }
    });
  });
  //next();
});
```

2 (better one):

```
router.use(function (req, res, next){
  DBCon.DBConUtil.pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
    if (err) throw new DBDataError("Error while getting connection from pool");
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM employee' ,function(err,rows){
      if(err){
        connection.release();
        throw new DBDataError("Error while executing select statement using pool connection.");
      }else{
        res.rows1 = rows;
        logger.info("App-Instance-name: %s, filename: %s, MessageContent: %s", process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE, __filename, JSON.stringify({message: "Data received from Db using connection pool: ", data: rows}));
        connection.release();
      }
      // Let express know this callback is done and it can resume the middleware process
      next();
    });
  });
});
```

Last note: please don't use res.send in middleware!

Comment: Hi, Both Solutions are not helping. Node is able to catch the exception when throws in call back methods but subsequently it's exiting.